# Why is this specific type of Numeronym acceptable?

Tags: usage

There are many characteristics of [Numeronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeronym).

Some are acceptable in my opinion. For example,

> "K9" for "canine" (phonetically: "kay" + "nine").

Suddenly I came across the word "i18n" from [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/xi18n), and it confused me so much on how to interpret that word. So I did some research and found out that the word "**i18n**" is the shorten form for "**internationalization**", which is a Numeronym.

I now know the history of it but I still does not feel right about how we shorten these kind of words like this. I think there must be a robust and convincing way to do it rather than "let's put the number of letters between the first letter and the last letter, and that's how we are gonna shorten that word."

The thing that stings me is that people will have a very hard time guessing the word it derives from, and also it just doesn't make any sense.

Okay, here is the question so that we have something to be a base to talk about.

Why is this specific type of Numeronym acceptable?
and is there some other ways to make it easier to understand more than this method of shortening a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short (and potentially unhelpful) answer is that English words are "acceptable" if a sufficient number of people understand them to mean something in a particular context and be the appropriate tone.

While "[i18n](http://www.i18nguy.com/origini18n.html)" is a very opaque way to abbreviate a word, if you use it in a context where "internationalization" is the only long word that makes sense in that spot, it could make sense to fluent speakers familiar with the context. Using jargon or abbreviations that are hard for people unfamiliar with the context to understand can be similar to an [inside joke](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/inside+joke) and be a way to make a particular group of people feel that text is written specifically for them, or that the author is a member of that group.